# Android KeyStore not generating same SHA value on a different computer for same project

Tags: android, google-maps, keystore

I am using google maps api in my android project and I have restricted the key access by package name and its SHA-1 value. When I use the same keystore and generate the signed apk from another computer of same project, I am unable to access the google maps as the SHA-1 value is different. The debug SHA-1 value works on both computers and for google maps api.

Can somebody advice me on why this is happening.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the issue. When using that keystore, I was doing create new rather than choose existing, hence, the SHA1 value was different.